# CSS styles acting differently in development vs production

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm having trouble with an css style applied to an overlay in a package called `react-popup`. The css style doesn't work properly in production, whereas it works correctly in development.

Basically these two classes seem to be the issue:

```
.mm-popup {
    display: none;
}
.mm-popup--visible {
    display: block;
}
```

In development it works, but in production `.mm-popup--visible` is always set to `display: none;`
it looks like it isn't even taking `.mm-pop--visible` into consideration and just using `.mm-popup.`

[image]

If I try and set it like this

```
.mm-popup .mm-popup--visible {
    display: block;
}
```

The opposite happens, it works in development but not in production.

[image]

Thoughts?

Comment: Actually when you are combining classes of same div done leave space, ryt now what u need is `.mm-popup.mm-popup--visible` without space.. Thing what your style considering is searching --visible as child of mm-popup but it's on same level. So you should use without space

Comment: @Rob The is images are necessary to show what the DOM is actually doing, and seeing as how its the output of the chrome debugger I don't think I'd say its an image of code? What code do you think would be more useful here?

Comment: @Manjunath I just tried that and there was no change.

Comment: Where did you add the css? Is css loaded with current changes? Can you check source from browser and verify if that styles are present?

Comment: @Manjunath the css is imported at index.js and yes I can see the the change was loaded by viewing the Styles in chrome debugger.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion combined with adding a `body` before, and it seems to have worked. Not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but it seems to be a specificity issue so I wanted to up its specificity.

Comment: Can u share screenshot same like above showing how browser is viewing the class?

Comment: @Manjunath actually I think you are right, it wasn't loaded. Sometimes if I make a change and run yarn build it doesn't reflect in the build. I did it again and it seems to be working with your suggestion alone. Thanks, if you want to make an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Yeah will add the sane comment as answer so it shows it's fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you are combining classes of same div done leave space, ryt now what u need is `.mm-popup.mm-popup--visible` without space.. Thing is that your style is searching `--visible` as child of `mm-popup` but it's on same level. So you should use without space

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a space between dashes in `mm-popup--visible`, you have made a typo it seems like `mm-popup- -visible`

Comment: Where are you seeing this typo? I don't see it in my css styles.